# How to filter within a Window Function PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I only want to filter in Window function to keep the `created_at is null` so I don't use `WHERE` clause previously. Because when I `order by created_at desc` it will show the null value first.

How to add a filter in this code?

```
select *, first_value(title) over (partition by product_id order by created_at desc)  as last_title
from t2
```

I try this `not work`:

```
select *, first_value(title) over (partition by product_id order by created_at desc) having (created_at is not null) as last_title
    from t2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the NULL values to the end:

```
first_value(title) over (partition by product_id order by created_at desc nulls last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below condition,

```
select *, first_value(title) over (partition by product_id order by created_at desc)  
as last_title
from t2 where created_at is not null
```